# How to transform the output of Minimize/Maximize into a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to create a function directly from the output of `Maximize`. Specifically, I have the following function $f(l,h,d,a)$ that I want to maximize with respect to $a$ subject to some constraints:

```
f[l_, h_, d_, a_] := (1 - d)*a*(h - a)/(h - l) + (d^2(a + l))/(2(1 + d))
```

Calling `Maximize[{f[l, h, d, a], 0 < l <= a <= h  && 0 < d < 1}, {a}]` yields a set of conditional expressions for different parameter constellations.

I would like to combine this output quickly and effectively into a new function $f_m(l,h,d)$. To me, the most obvious possibility is to do this:

```
fm1[l_, h_, d_] := First@Maximize[{f[l, h, d, a], 0 < l <= a <= h  && 0 < d < 1}, {a}]
```

This works but is slow, presumably because `Maximize` is evaluated  every time the function is called. I have worked around this issue the following way:

```
m = Maximize[{f[l, h, d, a], 0 < l <= a <= h  && 0 < d < 1}, {a}];
mm = m /. {l -> ll, h -> hh, d -> dd};
fm2[l_, h_, d_] :=
  If[mm[[1, 1, 1, 2]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d}, 
     mm[[1, 1, 1, 1]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d},
  If[mm[[1, 1, 2, 2]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d}, 
     mm[[1, 1, 2, 1]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d},
  If[mm[[1, 1, 3, 2]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d}, 
     mm[[1, 1, 3, 1]] /. {ll -> l, hh -> h, dd -> d}, -infinity]]]
```

This works as well but is pretty inconvenient to do for larger output and most likely not the best way to do this. However, it evaluates much faster:

```
fm1[1, 6, .8] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.109200, 1.26864}

fm2[1, 6, .8] // AbsoluteTiming
{0., 1.26864}
```

My question therefore is: Is there a convenient way to transform the output of `Maximize` into an efficient new function $f_m$ without having to copy and paste expressions and conditions by hand?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Try using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` for defining fm1 (`fm1[l_, h_, d_] = First@Maximize[{f[l, h, d, a],...`)

Comment: Sascha's comment hit the nail on the head: using `Set` will execute `Maximize` once only and save the result for future use. Furthermore, since you only seem to care about the maximum value, and not the value of the parameter at the maximum, you may want to use [`MaxValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html) instead of `Maximise`, so you will not need to apply `First` to the results, and improve the legibility of your code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in my comment, the solution is to use `Set` (`=`) for the "function definition" instead of `SetDelayed`(`:=`). The reason is that `Set` evaluates the **r.h.s** of `l.h.s. = r.h.s.` (abbreviations for left- and right-hand-side) once and whenever Mathematica encounters **l.h.s** it gets replaced with the evaluated form of **r.h.s**. `SetDelayed` on the other hand reevaluates **r.h.s.** whenever it encounters **l.h.s.**

In your example using `SetDelayed` introduces a performance penalty since the evaluation of `Maximize`is costly and it gets evaluated every time you call your "function" - the returned expression (your "function") **in this case** is the same for both `Set` and `SetDelayed` however since your function always evaluates to the same expression given the same input parameters.

Comment: Very nice. I would also recommend to look at the `InputForm` of the `First` part of the solution. I needed that in order to understand that it was a `Piecewise` function.